# iTextSharp check the annotation type

Tags: pdf, annotations, itext

I am trying to extract annotations from PDFs, At the moment I can read all annotations using this code.

```
    Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("MyPDF.pdf")

    For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
        Dim array As PdfArray = reader.GetPageN(i).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS)
        If array Is Nothing Then Continue For

        For j As Integer = 0 To array.Size - 1
            Dim annot As PdfDictionary = array.GetAsDict(j)
            Dim name As PdfString = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.T)
            Dim text As PdfString = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS)
        Next
    Next
```

Now, I would like to check the type of annotation, so I can cross out the not so important ones to me in example. shapes;

- Sticky Note
- Text highlight
- Text Underline
- Text Strikethrough
- Line
- Arrow
- ....

But I can't find any samples on this matter. I tried searching for documentation but again I am failing to understand.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried searching for documentation but again I am failing to understand

As you are accessing the annotations using the very low level API layer of itext, you are pretty near to the pdf content itself. Thus, the documentation to look for in this context is the pdf specification ISO 32000.

Adobe has published an older version, ISO 32000-1, on its web pages:

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

In section 12.5 "Annotations" you'll find lots of information on annotations. In particular that the type of annotation described by an annotation dictionary is given as the value of **Subtype**. The sub type value for the specified annotation types can be found in the sub section focusing on the annotation type in question.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will digg into it. But I am also curious, is there a better documented way to accomplish this. Big note is that it has to be free.

Comment: It's difficult to find a better documentation than the specification (even though the specification is unclear in some aspects...)

Comment: There is indeed no better (or other?) documentation than the specification.